# Remove comma and change string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to find "money" in a file and change the `string` to `float` , for example, I use regular expression to find "$33,326" and would like to change to [33326.0, "$"] (i.e., remove comma, $ sign and change to `float`). I wrote the following function but it gives me an error

```
import locale,re
def currencyToFloat(x):
    empty = []
    reNum = re.compile(r"""(?P<prefix>\$)?(?P<number>[.,0-9]+)(?P<suffix>\s+[a-zA-Z]+)?""")
    new = reNum.findall(x)
    for i in new:
        i[1].replace(",", "")
        float(i[1])
        empty.append(i[1])
        empty.append(i[0])
    return empty

print currencyToFloat("$33,326")
```

Can you help me debug my code?

Comment: Can you provide the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
float(i[1])
```

you are not modifying anything. You should store the result in some variable, like:

```
temp = ...
```

But to cast to `float` your number have to have a dot, not a comma, so you can do:

```
temp = i[1].replace(",", ".")
```

and then cast it to float and append to the list:

```
empty.append(float(temp))
```

**Note:**

Something important you should know is that when you loop through a list, like

```
for i in new:
```

`i` is a copy of each element, so if you modify it, no changes will be done in the list `new`. To modify the list you can iterate over the indices:

```
for i in range(len(new)):
    new[i] = ...
```

Comment: I vote for your answer and select it as the best. But I do not know who vote it down...sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

```
money = "$33,326"
money_list = [float("".join(money[1:].split(","))), "$"]
print(money_list)
```

OUTPUT

[33326.0, '$']

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.translate()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```
>>>money= "$333,26"
>>>float(money.translate(None, ",$"))
33326.0
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3 you can use [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) with [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate):

```
money = "$33,326"
print('money: {}'.format(float(money.translate(str.maketrans('', '', ",$")))))
```

Output: `money: 33326.0`